# Recursive cdef class in Cython

Tags: class, recursion, cython

I have a python class that takes objects of the same class as arguments. I thought transposing it to a Cython cdef class (extension type) would not be allowed. Surprisingly, it seems to work.

```python
cdef class NodeObject:
    cdef NodeObject parent

    @staticmethod
    cdef create_node(NodeObject parent=None):
        cdef NodeObject no=NodeObject()
        no.parent=parent
        return no

cdef NodeObject node_0=NodeObject.create_node()
cdef NodeObject node_1=NodeObject.create_node(parent=node_0)

print (node_0.parent,node_1.parent)

-----------------------------------------------------------
>>>"(None, <tests.NodeObject object at 0x00000203105BACC0>)"
```

My questions:
I know recursive structs are impossible in C, but what happens in this case?
Is it safe to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to use, because `cdef NodeObject parent` is a pointer on the C-level.

While

```
struct Foo{
   struct  Foo a;
};
```

is not allowed (because, among other things, what is `sizeof(Foo)`?), the usage of a pointer to a `Foo`-object in `struct Foo` is completely fine:

```
struct Foo{
   struct  Foo *a;
};
```

Here it is quite easy to say what is the size of a `Foo`-object: for example on my Linux64 it is 8 bytes.

As Cython translates

```
cdef class NodeObject:
    cdef NodeObject parent
```

to

```
struct __pyx_obj_5xxxxx_NodeObject {
  PyObject_HEAD
  struct __pyx_obj_5xxxxx_NodeObject *parent;
};
```

there is no danger in using it.